# Emacs in console/terminal mode menus

Tags: emacs

I've searched but couldn't find an answer to: how do I select the: **File, Edit, Options, Buffers, Tools, C++**, etc. drop-down menus when running Emacs in console mode? Not the terminal menus.

And no, F10 ain't the answer.

Comment: If F10 ain't the answer, what's the question?

Comment: Perhaps better asked at [emacs.se]?

Answer (score 2):

If not F10, then `M-x menu-bar-open` ?

Comment: Bingo! That does it. Thanks.

Comment: @jski: `C-h k f10` would have told you that!